# how best to combine multiple select statements to create single dataset for report

Tags: mysql, sql, count, pivot, where-clause

I currently have 3 select statements that pull user login info for day shift, night shift and saturday. i want to combine all these into single query/dataset i can then use to pull single report/chart in our BI tool.
Running these each individually gives my correct output but want to combine so can then generate report/graph with each overlayed.

Any help is appreciated.

```
SELECT
  DATE(users_logins.login_time - INTERVAL 7 HOUR) AS Date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT users_logins.user_id) AS `Number of Unique Users DayShift`
FROM users_logins
WHERE TIME(users_logins.login_time - INTERVAL 7 HOUR) >= '04:00:00'
AND TIME(users_logins.login_time - INTERVAL 7 HOUR) < '16:30:00'
AND WEEKDAY(DATE(users_logins.login_time - INTERVAL 7 HOUR)) BETWEEN 0 AND 4
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY Date DESC

SELECT
  DATE(users_logins.login_time - INTERVAL 7 HOUR) AS Date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT users_logins.user_id) AS `Number of Unique Users NightShift`
FROM users_logins
WHERE TIME(users_logins.login_time - INTERVAL 7 HOUR) >= '16:30:00'
AND TIME(users_logins.login_time - INTERVAL 7 HOUR) < '21:00:00'
AND WEEKDAY(DATE(users_logins.login_time - INTERVAL 7 HOUR)) BETWEEN 0 AND 4
GROUP BY 1
    ORDER BY Date DESC

SELECT
  DATE(users_logins.login_time - INTERVAL 7 HOUR) AS Date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT users_logins.user_id) AS `Number of Unique Users Saturday`
FROM users_logins
WHERE TIME(users_logins.login_time - INTERVAL 7 HOUR) >= '04:00:00'
AND TIME(users_logins.login_time - INTERVAL 7 HOUR) < '21:00:00'
AND WEEKDAY(DATE(users_logins.login_time - INTERVAL 7 HOUR)) = 5
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation. The idea is to move the conditions to within aggregate expressions. I would also recommend offsetting the date in a subquery, so there is no need to repeat the expression in the query.

So:

```
SELECT
    DATE(login_time) AS Date,
    COUNT(DISTINCT  
        CASE WHEN TIME(login_time) >= '04:00:00' 
              AND TIME(login_time) <  '16:30:00'  
              AND WEEKDAY(DATE(login_time)) BETWEEN 0 AND 4
        THEN user_id
        END
    ) AS `Number of Unique Users DayShift`,
    COUNT(DISTINCT  
        CASE WHEN TIME(login_time) >= '16:30:00' 
              AND TIME(login_time) <  '21:00:00'  
              AND WEEKDAY(DATE(login_time)) BETWEEN 0 AND 4
        THEN user_id
        END
    ) AS `Number of Unique Users NightShift`,
    COUNT(DISTINCT  
        CASE WHEN TIME(login_time) >= '04:00:00' 
              AND TIME(login_time) <  '21:00:00' 
              AND WEEKDAY(DATE(login_time)) = 5           
        THEN user_id
        END
    ) AS `Number of Unique Users DayShift`
FROM (SELECT login_time - INTERVAL 7 HOUR login_time, user_id FROM users_logins) u
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Comment: Thanks very much, i see what did there to make login_time = to the 7hour offset outside of the main query so would just use login_time . I am getting info back now i expect.

Comment: GMB, one more question any idea how to limit user ids pulled for the nightshift since some users work later then 1630 that start during day shift, so its inflating the # of users in night shift ? thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION for this purpose, I believe you'll need to put the ORDER BY at the end instead of in each SELECT :

```
SELECT
  DATE(users_logins.login_time - INTERVAL 7 HOUR) AS Date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT users_logins.user_id) AS `Number of Unique Users DayShift`
FROM users_logins
WHERE TIME(users_logins.login_time - INTERVAL 7 HOUR) >= '04:00:00'
AND TIME(users_logins.login_time - INTERVAL 7 HOUR) < '16:30:00'
AND WEEKDAY(DATE(users_logins.login_time - INTERVAL 7 HOUR)) BETWEEN 0 AND 4
GROUP BY 1

UNION

SELECT
  DATE(users_logins.login_time - INTERVAL 7 HOUR) AS Date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT users_logins.user_id) AS `Number of Unique Users NightShift`
FROM users_logins
WHERE TIME(users_logins.login_time - INTERVAL 7 HOUR) >= '16:30:00'
AND TIME(users_logins.login_time - INTERVAL 7 HOUR) < '21:00:00'
AND WEEKDAY(DATE(users_logins.login_time - INTERVAL 7 HOUR)) BETWEEN 0 AND 4
GROUP BY 1

UNION 

SELECT
  DATE(users_logins.login_time - INTERVAL 7 HOUR) AS Date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT users_logins.user_id) AS `Number of Unique Users Saturday`
FROM users_logins
WHERE TIME(users_logins.login_time - INTERVAL 7 HOUR) >= '04:00:00'
AND TIME(users_logins.login_time - INTERVAL 7 HOUR) < '21:00:00'
AND WEEKDAY(DATE(users_logins.login_time - INTERVAL 7 HOUR)) = 5
GROUP BY 1

ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, yes i had tried that only issue is im only getting Number of Unique Users Dayshift column with all results under there. I need to have those #s under their individual column (Dayshift/nightshift/saturday)

Comment: @kyuzon:  then in your first select you have to do `SELECT value, 0, 0 FROM...` in the second you do ` SELECT 0,value, 0....` and in the third you do `SELECT 0,0,value...`. After this you probably need to `GROUP BY`...